# HTML form submission from java requires cookies and a popup blocker

Tags: java, html

I am using POST to submit a form to a web-based login server from a java application.

However, the webpage requires both cookies and a popup blocker, which are detected and handled in an init() javascript function:

```
if (document.cookie == "") {
        alert("Cookies are disabled. Cannot access server with this setting.\nPlease configure your browser to accept cookies.");
        return;
    }

detectPopupBlockers();
```

It appears that cookies are only ever used in the detectPopupBlockers() function (to indicate that a message has already been shown if the user does not have a popup blocker enabled).

Is there a way I can completely avoid the init() function that is called by the onload parameter?  Or somehow emulate that cookies and a popup blocker are in fact enabled?  My only guess at a third option is to somehow dismiss the popup message telling me I have no cookies and submit the form anyway.

Comment: If you're programatically submitting the form, how does this Javascript ever run to generate a problem? Perhaps there server just expecting your request to come with a cookie (in which case, just write your code to obey the Cookie header it sends you, then remake the request).

Comment: Please excuse me, I'm fairly new to this, but your question seems valid. The script shouldn't even run. Is there something wrong with the way I am submitting the POST request? PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( myHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream() ); ps.print("username=" + username + "&amp;pwd=" + password.toString());

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using something like WebClient to do the posting - couldn't you just disable Javascript and bypass the checks altogether?

Comment: I am just using java's HttpURLConnection class, nothing like WebClient

Answer (score 1):

If it bound like so:

```
<body onload="init();">
```

Or like this:

```
document.body.onload = init;
```

You can just do this:

```
document.body.onload = null;
```

Directly under the body tag.